# Is that normal for the PI to track their student in social media and even through the work?

Tags: advisor, time-management

Long story short, I am writing this on behalf of friend of mine for a different perspective. His supervisor is tracking them in each step, e.g. track the time on a Google Sheets when my friend worked or not, even on social media, his supervisor always gives non-constructive feedback and attacks him in front of everyone for nonsense. My friend is a scientific blogger and sometimes the supervisor asks him not to work on blogging in a humiliating way and should instead spend all the day on research.

Is this normal behavior that should be expected from a supervisor in academia?

Answer (score 4):

It is not easy to answer such questions, as they offer a very one-sided perspective of what is really happening. But note a couple of things:

1. Your "friend" may be a scientific blogger, but he is also a PhD students with this supervisor. The blogging activity does not (fully) substitute the research / investigation / writing activities that are expected from a PhD student.
2. A little bit of activity on social media during the work hours *can* be tolerated, but extensive engagement with blogging at the expense of research is not cool. To achieve PhD, your friend will need to develop some work ethics and discipline, which also includes a skill of keeping dedicated hours for specific tasks.
3. Micro-managing and stalking on social media are not cool either. However, if your friend blogs a lot, their supervisor probably did not have to search very much to find evidence that the student spends their work hours on something else that is expected from them. Most supervisors won't really care when their students do research and when they blog, as long as research is going well. Perhaps, supervisor is frustrated that your friend has neglected their main research duties?

Answer (score 3):

The way you formulate the question means that the answer has to be that that is not OK. But that answer says more about your question than about the actual situation your friend is in. You have formulated your question such that we could not have come to a different answer.

So the real question is, is that what is actually happening? I don't doubt that you are genuinely concerned about your friend, and that your friend feels that this is what is happening to him. In some countries you are employed as a PhD student, and your employer has the right, within certain limits, to ensure that their employees work during working hours. For most PhD students this is their first experience as a serious full time employee, and some handle it better than others. Add to that that professors are hired not for their management skills, so there is some variance in how skilled they are in handling personal issues. This can lead to lots of ugly misunderstandings.

Now, the student not just an employee, but also there to learn, and the professor not just there to supervise but also to teach. So a big part of the responsibility to fix the situation lies with the professor. But (s)he cannot do that alone. If your friend approaches this problem as "you're a bad person, now fix the situation", then that is not going to work. So if your friend wants the situation to get better, then he also has to get proactive.